# React Redux failing to create persistent storage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React and Redux. Please help me to resolve the React-Redux failing to create persistent storage error in the below code -

Action -

```
        export const actionTypes = {
        LOGIN_REQUEST: 'LOGIN_REQUEST',
        LOGIN_SUCCESS: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
        LOGOUT: 'LOGOUT',
        LOGOUT_SUCCESS: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS',
        CHECK_AUTHORIZATION: 'CHECK_AUTHORIZATION',    
    };
        export function IsUserLoggedIn(payload) {   
            return { 
                 type: actionTypes.CHECK_AUTHORIZATION,
                 payload,
                };
        }
        export function login() {
            return { type: actionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST };
        }
        
        export function loginSuccess() {
            return { type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS };
        }
export function logOutSuccess() {
    return { type: actionTypes.LOGOUT_SUCCESS };
}
```

Reducer -

```
    import { actionTypes } from './action';
    
    export const initState = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
    };
    
    function reducer(state = initState, action) {
    
        switch (action.type) {   
case actionTypes.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...{ isLoggedIn: false },
            };     
            case actionTypes.CHECK_AUTHORIZATION:       
                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...{ isLoggedIn: false },
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    export default reducer;
```

Saga -

```
function* isUserLoggedInSaga({ payload }) {  
    try {   
        const data = yield call(AuthRepository.isUserLoggedIn, payload);   
        yield put(IsUserLoggedIn(data));
    } catch (err) { 
        console.log(err);
    }
}

export default function* rootSaga() { 
    yield all([takeEvery(actionTypes.LOGOUT, logOutSaga)]);   
    yield all([takeEvery(actionTypes.CHECK_AUTHORIZATION, isUserLoggedInSaga)]);
}
```

code reaches till "yield put(IsUserLoggedIn(data));" in Saga and it throw error on this line.Please help to resolve the issue.

If "yield put(IsUserLoggedIn(data));" is replaced with yield put(logOutSuccess()); then code works fine

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: ```Export const actionTypes = {.....``` export should be ```export const .....```

Comment: It does not give any error...page gets stuck....

Comment: Page keep on showing loading

Comment: I see your action with CHECK_AUTHORIZATION type uses a payload, and your reducer does not use this payload in the switch. I havent seen all the code thou.